# Post method and String value in Java Spring

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I'm trying to post a text from home.html template

```
   <form th:action="@{/process_addText}" th:object="${textzz}" method="post"  >
        
        <input type="text"  th:field="*{text}"  />
    
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-info">Add</button>
    </form>
```

and here is my controller

```
@PostMapping("/process_addText")
public String processAddText(Text text1) {
    Authentication auth = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
    String name = auth.getName();
    User myUser=userRepo.findByEmail(name);
    text1.setUser(myUser);
    textRepo.save(text1);

    return "redirect:/home";
}


@GetMapping("/home")
public String mySuccess(Model model) {
    model.addAttribute("textzz",new Text());
    LOGGER.info("verif==="+model.toString());
    return "home";
}
```

And it's my Text class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "texts")

public class Text {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long idText;

    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "id", referencedColumnName = "id")
    private User user;

    private String text;
}
```

when I'm trying to post the "text" value from home.html,I'm getting this error:

> WARN 680 --- [nio-8088-exec-7]
> .w.s.m.s.DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver : Resolved
> [org.springframework.beans.TypeMismatchException: Failed to convert
> value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type
> 'com.myblog.app.model.Text'; nested exception is
> org.springframework.core.convert.ConversionFailedException: Failed to
> convert from type [java.lang.String] to type [java.lang.Long] for
> value 'qvefd'; nested exception is java.lang.NumberFormatException:
> For input string: "qvefd"]

I have no idea why I'm getting this, because the types are correct

Update: When I remove the input and I post(without text) in my DB I get correct rows(for text id and User's foreign key), of course with text value=NULL. So the problem is in type of input, maybe.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your controller method accepts a `Text` entity but your frontend form sends with post request only a simple `String` in the body of the request.

Then Spring can not transform that `String` into a `Text` object.

So your controller method should be

```
@PostMapping("/process_addText")
public String processAddText(String text) {
    Authentication auth = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
    String name = auth.getName();
    User myUser=userRepo.findByEmail(name);

    Text text1 = textRepo.findByUser(myUser);
    if (text1 == null){
       text1 = new Text();
       text1.setUser(myUser);
    }
    text1.setText(text);
    textRepo.save(text1);

    return "redirect:/home";
}
```

Comment: thanks, I modified a little bit the question, I want to use an object parameter,because I want to post some other fields(other than the text), the String data parameter will not allow me to do that.Is it right?

Comment: and your answer is totally right,it resolves my current problem,thank you.